# Apply css string to div using jquery (issue with URL background image)

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm using this code to upload and attach background image to class:

```
// part of ajax
success: function(data) {
                let url = 'https://example.digitaloceanspaces.com/' + data.url;
$('.product_header').css({"background-image":"url('" + url + "')"});

//saving style attribute to global variable
                styles = $('.product_header').attr('style');
                
            },
```

the string has been saved like: `'background: url(\"https://example.digitaloceanspaces.com/L0zk2.png\");'`

after that I'm need to use style string to attach and I'm trying to implement string like this:

```
$('#product_header').append('<div class="product_header" data-slide-to="11" style="' + style + '"></div>');
```

but when I check browser console its rendered like:

```
<div class="product_header" style="background: url(" https:="" pdfdocs.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com="" l0zk2.png");"=""></div>
```

and it wont show correctly background image.

How I can solve this problem? I was thinking that .append in jquery remove 'slash' from URL but why ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have an extra set of quotation marks in this line:

```
$('.product_header').css({"background-image":"url('" + url + "')"});
```

Try changing it to:

```
$('.product_header').css({"background-image":"url(" + url + ")"});
```

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-set-css-background-image-property-using-jquery.php

Comment: sorry no, the same problem again